# What is Openlayers.ProxyHost?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

Actually am a newbie on this field.I didn't understand about Openlayers.ProxyHost.And i also don't know about Cross server thing??

Answer (score 3):

Cross Site scripting is a security issue related to running javascript code loaded from sources other than the one the web page is loaded from: [Wikipedia](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=xss&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting&ei=pkmyTsWhEuGziQK29LVy&usg=AFQjCNGGfyJjOyiWYPB3FW-h7Pt6A5uwlA&sig2=O56yYD9xqGn_6vJRdJv1yQ)

ProxyHost could be used to "simulate" a local request to a remote location. [OpenLayers documentation](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost)

Comment: Will you please tell me about proxy script.I have geoserver running on port 8080 and glassfish on 9999 port

Comment: have you read the documentation? Do you even need a ProxyHost?